# Find all solutions satisfying $|x|+|y|<10 000$ given diophantine equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Im trying to find all solutions satisfying  $|x|+|y|<10 000$ given the Diophantine equation

$$1619x + 460y = 100 $$

I've already found $x$ and $y$ using Euclides algoritm that

$$x=17900+460k$$
$$y=-63000-1619k$$

Now to the part im stuck on. I realized I want to keep the inequality from $$|x|+|y|< 10000$$ to be able to find some interval for which $k$ it is satisfied.

Given $x$ and $y$:

$$|17900+460k|+|-63000-1619k|<10 000$$

The part I need help understanding is how to handle the abs signs to solve this mathematically.

I do know I can simply first find for what $x$ and $y$ that minimizes the Diophantine equation, and simply try different $k$ that satisfies it, but I want to solve it mathematically without guessing game.

Would anyone like to give me hint on how to handle the abs. signs and how to solve it? :)

Comment: There are 4 cases: $x$ is positive/negative and $y$ is positive/negative. For each case solve the appropriate inequality by dropping the absolute values correctly.

Comment: Okey thanks! So I assume I will get 4 inequalities for k less than or greater than som value. Just so I understand this correct, do I want the k in the answer to satisfy all inequalities? Or what do I do with all 4 intervals?

Comment: You can't have a $k$ that satisfies all inequalities. Each pair of inequalities corresponds to $(x,y)$ being in one of the four quadrants. The only point which is in all quadrants is $(0,0)$, and you can't get $(0,0)$ for any $k$. 

You will get an interval or a union of intervals for the possible values of $k$. You then need to take every (integral) $k$ and plug it into $(x,y)$ to get all the solutions.

Comment: HINT.-$$|A|+|B|\lt N \iff \left||A|+|B|\right|\lt N\iff -N\lt|A|+|B|\lt N$$ so four inequations $$-N\lt A+B\lt N\\-N\lt A-B\lt N\\-N\lt -A+B\lt N\\-N\lt -A-B\lt N$$